# Is it possible to create a custom instance type on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

One of our applications uses a lot of memory but not much CPU. We are using m4.2xlarge, which means we have 32 GB ram & 8 cores. As per my requirement we need 4 cores and 8gb ram.I searched for these combination of instance type but i didn't get that.So,is there any chance to create custom instance type.

Comment: Its not possible. As an alternative you could get one huge instance and run docker containers on it with all your hardware needs configured.

Comment: Consider a t2.xl or an m4.xl? This will be cheaper than an m4.2xl. The cores you will see in AWS dont necessarily correspond to the same computnig power of a physical core, for reference, so dont assume 4 physical core requirement so easily translates to 4 cores in cloud.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid there is no such thing as custom EC2 instance type. You'll need to select one from the offered EC2 instance classes.

Also, your assumption about the number of cores for the `m4.2xlarge` instance is incorrect. An `m4.2xlarge` instance has 4 virtual cores, not 8. See [Virtual Cores by Amazon EC2 and RDS DB Instance Type](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/virtualcores/).

According to [this](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/), each vCPU is a hyperthread of an Intel Xeon core (except for T2 and m3.medium instances). AWS does not guarantee anything beyond that.

So, if you want a 4 virtual CPU (i.e., 2 virtual cores x 2 hyperthreads per core = 4 vCPU) instance with 7.5 GiB RAM, you can select the `c4.xlarge` instance.

Comment: You might consider clarifying `(i.e., 2 virtual cores)` as `(i.e., 2 virtual cores × 2 hyperthreads per core = 4 vCPU)` for the benefit of those who might not immediately see how you switched from 4 back to 2, here.  You're correct, but my initial reaction was "wait, what?"

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Edited as you suggested. Thank you for your feedback, Michael :)